# How to get photos from getExternalFilesDir

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

I am implementing a gallery app where i want to use photpos stored in getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) directory .. Here is the code but what i get is all the gallery photo pictures , how can i figure this out :

```
    public class GalleryPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityGalleryPhotoBinding binding;
ArrayList<Uri> imageuris= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding= ActivityGalleryPhotoBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        String [] projection=new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
        };
        String selection=null;
        String[] selectionArgs =null;
        String orderby=null;
        Uri content_uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(content_uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,orderby);
        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToPosition(0);
            while(true){
                long id= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
                Uri image_uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,id);

                imageuris.add(image_uri);
                if(!cursor.isLast())
                cursor.moveToNext();
                else
                    break;
            }
            binding.rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
            RvAdapter adapter = new RvAdapter(imageuris);
            binding.rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: You say you get all pictures. But i think you get nothing from getExternalFilesDir() as MediaStore will not index files located there.

Comment: @blackapps i am talking about gallery photos when i have mentinned "all pictures" .. But i want to get pictures from getExternalFilesDir()

Comment: Well i asked you if all pictures means inclusive those from getExternalFilesDir(). Please answer.

Comment: "I am implementing a gallery app" -- use `MediaStore` please, not filesystem APIs.

Comment: @blackapps okay , got you now . Yes , you are right . i am getting nothing from from getExternalFilesDir()

Comment: And you also know why? You should know it already. I told you why. But you are not reacting on it with a question that brings you further.

Comment: What is missing in your post from the beginning is that you did not tell how those image files landed in getExternalFilesDir().